# Changing datatype of column on Live DB

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm using hibernate to map my java class into a table in mySQL Database on Production... one record inside a integer column is causing a problem because it's exceeding that integer max value. My solution was to alter the column and then change the column type to bigint but it looks like it's not working... and changing it from the code won't work as well I guess because after hibernate creates the table then we can't change the datatype anymore...Would it be safe if I create a new bigint column and copy the records of the old column into it, drop the old column and then rename the new column?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Where did you alter the column? In Mysql table directly or only in Java code?

Comment: in mysql table... ddl-auto is set to none on prod btw